# conditional formatting in dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-formatting

I have a pandas data frame and I need to classify it based on the specified condition. The threshold is fixed and it has to be classified based on 8 different combinations of the threshold.

```
Threshold (A => 7, B = 3 or 4, C = between 22 - 27)
```

I tried using pandas with conditional operations to classify the data but it produces misleading results.

Conditions are:

```
1. class1=f[(f['A']>7.0)&((f['B']==3.0)|(f['B']==4.0))& ((f['C']>=22.0)&(f['C']<=27.0))]
2. class2=f[(f['A']>7.0)&((f['B']==3.0)|(f['B']==4.0))& ((f['C']<=22.0)&(f['C']>=27.0))]
3. class3=f[(f['A']<7.0)&((f['B']==3.0)|(f['B']==4.0))& ((f['C']>=22.0)&(f['C']<=27.0))]
4. class4=f[(f['A']>7.0)&((f['B']!=3.0)&(f['B']!=4.0))& ((f['C']>=22.0)&(f['C']<=27.0))]
5. class5=f[(f['A']>7.0)&((f['B']!=3.0)&(f['B']!=4.0))& ((f['C']<=22.0)&(f['C']>=27.0))]
6. class6=f[(f['A']<7.0)&((f['B']==3.0)|(f['B']==4.0))& ((f['C']<=22.0)&(f['C']>=27.0))]
7. class7=f[(f['A']<7.0)&((f['B']!=3.0)&(f['B']!=4.0))& ((f['C']>=22.0)&(f['C']<=27.0))]
8. class8=f[(f['A']<7.0)|((f['B']!=3.0)&(f['B']!=4.0))| ((f['C']<=22.0)&(f['C']>=27.0))]
```

I need all rows in the data frame to be classified based on the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your situation**: your dataframe is called `f` and contains 3 columns with numeric values. The columns are called `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'`.

**I recommend** doing it by creating boolean columns and combining them to match your classes. There are probably many more ways to do this, also much more elegant ones. I think this solution is as simple as they get. Essentially, you have three conditions that can be met:

```
check_a = f['A'] >= 7
check_b = (f['B'] == 3) | (f['B'] == 4)
check_c = (22 <= f['C'] <= 27)
```

Combining these 3 checks will construct your 8 cases (`~` negates the booleans, so basically flipping their values):

```
f['class_1'] =  check_a &  check_b &  check_c
f['class_2'] =  check_a &  check_b & ~check_c
f['class_3'] = ~check_a &  check_b &  check_c
f['class_4'] =  check_a & ~check_b &  check_c
f['class_5'] =  check_a & ~check_b & ~check_c
f['class_6'] = ~check_a &  check_b & ~check_c
f['class_7'] = ~check_a & ~check_b &  check_c
f['class_8'] = ~check_a & ~check_b & ~check_c
```

One of the reason your code doesn't work, is that you are checking whether the values in column `'C'` are both smaller than 22 AND larger than 27. This can never be true.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the same boolean cases with “or” and it executed successfully.